# How to create a property on a dynamic object using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic

How can do I create a property on a dynamic object at runtime using reflection?

The name of the property will only be known at runtime, not compile time.

Comment: You mean _add_ to the _type definition_ a new property? I don't think that's possible. Perhaps you should look at using [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) or using a `Dictionary<string, YourType>` lookup instead? EDIT: Perhaps I misread: are you using a [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd264741.aspx) type and want to add a property to it?

Comment: I would recommend creating a dynamic object (and maybe this is a good opportunity to use IronPython as well) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461504.aspx

Comment: By not using reflection :-) Reflection and dynamic objects in general don't work very well together.

Comment: Funny how this site has gone down hill in the quality of admins - 'I can't understand the question, down vote it...'. Did you see someone managed to answer the question precisely and clearly without anymore information...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
dynamic data = new ExpandoObject();
var dataDictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)data;

//add property
dataDictionary.Add("Name", "AwkwardCoder");

//access
var name = data.Name;
```

Comment: You answer actually answers his question, I misunderstood what he was asking for by the looks of it!

Comment: I4V, Robert Rouhani, Arran, Matthew, Liam  - this is how you answer a question